# Adding a primary key I.D to a foreign key I.D column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 mysql tables:

- vendor
- promotion

This is a PHP/MYSQL set-up.

The vendor and promotion tables are both using an auto-increment I.D as their primary key and vendor I.D is a foreign key in the promotion table.

I would like to be able to do an insert from the vendors account which they log into from a .php, so that when they add a promotion their primary key is added into the foreign key column (row for that specific promotion) so that I can query the promotion table for which vendors issued which promotions.

I've read into doing this as a trigger on the DB with a last_ID(), but is there an easier way that I can do this with the insert statement?

Something along these lines:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO promotion(description,price,vendorID (fk)) VALUES('$description','$price','','$surname','$tel',)";SET @VendorID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO
  promotion
   (VendorID, ...)
VALUES
  (@vendorID, ...)
```

Or perhaps something similar? I just need this as an SQL statement that I can use as my SQL skills are pretty basic.

Comment: So the vendor is logged in to your site and adds a promotion himself? You somehow have to know who is adding the promotion (so which vendor is meant). Save e.g. the `vendorid` as a session variable and use it (or something else that identifies the vendor and can be used to query the correct `vendorid`, you can query it directly during insert if your want - but what ever you tried to code in your example looks wrong).

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do, so I guess I can just add '.$_SESSION['id'].' to the values. I'll have a play with this and see if it works but thank you so much for the reply it's really helped put me in the right direction.